# AuthzForce failed update policies

Tags: fiware, policy, pdp, authzforce

I'm assigning permission (only access to /resource1) to a role.
However Keyrock give me a error 'Failed to update policies in Access Control GE'.

So, even when I request the resource2 (not resource1) with an access token that has the permission that can access resource1 only, AuthzForce permit the access because policies are not updated (it might be other problem).

The question is why authzforce cannot update policy?

Now, I successfully linked permission to the role (except for failing policy update), and I assigned the role to the user. Then I double checked configurations of Keyrock and AuthzForce. They are connected well I think.

[Error msg of Keyrock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njTcT.png)

[What makes I think AuthzForce is working well (this is the Wilma's successful log when I send a access request to Wilma with the access token)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeZJk.png)

Please refer above images, and below configuretion and environment.

```
// 'local_settings.py' in Keyrock
ACCESS_CONTROL_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
ACCESS_CONTROL_MAGIC_KEY = 'abcdefghijkmn'
```

My Env.:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Keyrock: 5.4.0 (https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm)
AuthzForce: 7.0.0
Wilma: 5.4.0 (https://github.com/ging/fiware-pep-proxy)
```

---

Error log (/var/log/tomcat7/authzforce-ce/error.log) when AuthzForce 5.4.1 is installed (The reason why I used AuthzForce 7.0.0). I used openjdk-7 and tomcat7 when I installed the authzforce-5.4.1.

```
2017-05-09 07:10:47,087|ERROR|localhost-startStop-2|org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader:324|Context initialization failed|
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getInitParameterNames(ApplicationContext.java:368) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getInitParameterNames(ApplicationContextFacade.java:367) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.registerEnvironmentBeans(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:201) ~[spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.postProcessBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:169) ~[spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:458) ~[spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) ~[spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) ~[spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:677) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1962) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_95]
2017-05-09 07:10:47,103|WARN |localhost-startStop-2|org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext:1052|Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent|
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue May 09 07:10:46 GMT-08:00 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1049) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:558) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5115) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5779) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:677) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1962) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_95]
2017-05-09 07:10:47,104|WARN |localhost-startStop-2|org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext:1060|Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close|
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue May 09 07:10:46 GMT-08:00 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:558) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5115) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5779) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:677) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1962) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_95]
2017-05-09 07:11:46,095|ERROR|localhost-startStop-1|org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader:324|Context initialization failed|
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getInitParameterNames(ApplicationContext.java:368) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getInitParameterNames(ApplicationContextFacade.java:367) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.registerEnvironmentBeans(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:201) ~[spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.postProcessBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:169) ~[spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:458) ~[spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) ~[spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) ~[spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:677) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1962) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_95]
2017-05-09 07:11:46,112|WARN |localhost-startStop-1|org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext:1052|Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent|
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue May 09 07:11:45 GMT-08:00 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1049) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:558) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5115) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5779) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:677) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1962) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_95]
2017-05-09 07:11:46,113|WARN |localhost-startStop-1|org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext:1060|Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close|
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue May 09 07:11:45 GMT-08:00 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:558) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5115) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5779) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:677) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1962) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_95]
2017-05-09 07:12:05,523|ERROR|localhost-startStop-1|org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader:324|Context initialization failed|
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getInitParameterNames(ApplicationContext.java:368) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getInitParameterNames(ApplicationContextFacade.java:367) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.registerEnvironmentBeans(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:201) ~[spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.postProcessBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:169) ~[spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:458) ~[spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) ~[spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) ~[spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:677) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1962) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_95]
2017-05-09 07:12:05,549|WARN |localhost-startStop-1|org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext:1052|Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent|
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue May 09 07:12:05 GMT-08:00 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1049) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:558) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5115) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5779) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:677) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1962) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_95]
2017-05-09 07:12:05,550|WARN |localhost-startStop-1|org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext:1060|Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close|
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue May 09 07:12:05 GMT-08:00 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010) [spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:558) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5115) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5779) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:677) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1962) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_95]
```

Comment: Which versions of KeyRock, AuthzForce and Wilma are you testing?

Comment: I am using latest versions. Keyrock is 5.3.0 (I checked ChangeLog file. I am using the code from https://hub.docker.com/r/ging/fiware-idm/), AuthzForce is 7.0.0, and Wilma version is I don't know but I used the code from https://github.com/ging/fiware-pep-proxy.

Comment: The latest version today should be KeyRock v5.4.1. Can you update? I am not the owner of KeyRock (but AuthzForce) though, so I will invite the owner of KeyRock to help on this one. For Wilma, you should checkout the tag 5.4 (latest release 5.4) on github. For AuthzForce, officially KeyRock and Wilma have been tested with AuthzForce 5.4.1. We can try to make this work with 7.0.0 but it may require a bit more effort.

Comment: I'm changing the versions according to your advice but AuthzForce 5.4.1 is not deployed successfully on tomcat (404 error when I request to localhost:8080/authzforce-ce/domains). There are a lot of errors in the log file. Should I install this with Ubuntu 14.04? I am using Ubuntu 16.04, openjdk-7 and tomcat7. Anyway, for your references I will update the errors of '/var/log/tomcat7/authzforce-ce/error.log' in my question. And I could not find the Keyrock 5.4.1 so I just installed github.com/ging/fiware-idm into my new environment. Thanks for your help @CyrilDangerville.

Comment: I did not notice that you are using Ubuntu 16.04. Indeed, AuthzForce 5.4.1 is **not** supported on Ubuntu 16.04. So let's stick with AuthzForce 7.0.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 for now. For KeyRock, the right git repo is https://github.com/ging/horizon (as mentioned in the install guide - http://fiware-idm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin_guide.html#step-by-step-installation). You can get release 5.4.1 from there. (The github link - github.com/ging/fiware-idm - given on the FIWARE catalogue and Docker page is obsolete as far as I know. It may be a good idea to report this issue on their new github.)

Comment: Thanks for your consistent support. It is all fixed with Keyrock 5.4.1. Level 2 (basic authorization) is working well with Keyrock 5.4.1, Wilma 5.4 and AuthzForce 7.0.0. Also, I had a problem that 'app_azf_domain' in access token did not create but it is solved too with Keyrock 5.4.1 (Before this, I created app_azf_domain manually).

Comment: OK so I posted the official answer below. So you can vote for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so the solution is to upgrade to KeyRock 5.4.1.